# Show that the trigonometric integral $\frac{\pi}{2}-\sin (x) \ll (1+x)^{-1}$.

Tags: integration, trigonometry

How can I show that for non-negative $x$ we have
$$
\int_x^{\infty} \frac{\sin(t)}{t} dt \ll (1+x)^{-1}.
$$
I think this should be an easy task but still I'm unable to solve it. I tried to estimate the absolute value of the integral but didn't get anything that converges and gives the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to bound:
$$\int_{0}^{N}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx = \lim_{\lambda\to 0}\int_{0}^{N}\frac{\sin(x)e^{-
\lambda x}}{x}\,dx $$
We may notice that for a fixed $N\in\mathbb{R}^+$, the function
$$ g(\lambda)=\int_{0}^{N}\frac{\sin(x)e^{-
\lambda x}}{x}\,dx$$
is very regular and its derivative is given by:
$$ g'(\lambda)=-\int_{0}^{N}\sin(x)e^{-\lambda x}\,dx = -\text{Im}\int_{0}^{N}e^{(i-\lambda)x}\,dx.$$
Since $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is a bounded function on $\mathbb{R}$, $\lim_{\lambda\to +\infty}g(\lambda)=0$, hence:
$$ g(\lambda) = \int_{\lambda}^{+\infty}\text{Im}\int_{0}^{N}e^{(i-t)x}\,dx\,dt=\int_{\lambda}^{+\infty}\text{Im}\frac{-1+e^{N(i-t)}}{i-t}\,dt $$
and:
$$ g(\lambda) = \int_{\lambda}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}-\frac{\cos N+t\sin N}{1+t^2}e^{-Nt}\right)\,dt$$
so that:
$$ g(0) = \int_{0}^{N}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos N+t\sin N}{1+t^2}e^{-Nt}\,dt$$
and the initial problem can be stated in the following way:

> $$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos x+t\sin x}{1+t^2}e^{-xt}\,dt \ll \frac{1}{x+1} $$

but that is trivial since the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives $\left|\frac{\cos x+t\sin x}{1+t^2}\right|\leq 1$ and $\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-xt}\,dt = \frac{1}{x}$.

The above argument can be stated just in terms of the Laplace transform:
$$\mathcal{L}\left(e^{-xt}\right) = \frac{1}{s+x},\qquad \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos x+t\sin x}{1+t^2}\right) = \sin(s+x)$$
give:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos x+t\sin x}{1+t^2}\,e^{-xt}\,dt = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(s+x)}{s+x}\,ds = \int_{x}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin s}{s}\,ds $$
as we know yet. In this case the Laplace transform is very useful since it removes the oscillations of the integrand function, giving us something more manageable. As an alternative,
$$\begin{eqnarray*} x\int_{x}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt = \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{x\sin(xu)}{u}\,du &=& -(1-\cos x)+\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos(xu)}{u^2}\,du\\&=&\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(x)-\cos(xu)}{u^2}\,du\end{eqnarray*}$$
is obviously bounded by $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{2\,du}{u^2}=2.$

Comment: Is it not the case that $\text{si}(x) = \cos x /x + \sin x/ x^2 + O(1/x^3)$ as $x \to \infty$.  How is it that  $\text{si}(x) \ll (1+x)^{-1}$?

Comment: @RRL: maybe because the sine and cosine functions are bounded by one in absolute value?

Comment: I was implying that it appears that $(1+x)\text{si}(x)$ was bounded but did not go to $0$ as $x \to \infty$. My misunderstanding then is the meaning of $\ll$.

Comment: @RRL: $f(x)\ll g(x)$ as $x\to +\infty$ exactly means that $\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|$ is bounded by some constant $C$ as $x\to +\infty$. Anyway, we are bounding $\frac{\pi}{2}-\text{Si}(x)$, not $\text{Si}(x)$.

Comment: Thanks -- I confused it with little-oh.  I do vaguely recall that sine and cosine are bounded. :)

Answer (score 0):

$si(x) 
= - \int_x^{\infty} \frac{\sin(t)}{t} dt 
\ll (1+x)^{-1}.
$

Integrating by parts
($\int u dv
=uv-\int v du
$)
with
$v = -\cos(t),
u = \frac1{t}
$
so
$du = -\frac1{t^2}$
and
$dv = \sin(t) dt$,
$\int \frac{\sin(t)}{t} dt 
=-\frac{\cos(t)}{t}-\int \frac{-\cos(t)}{-t^2}dt
=-\frac{\cos(t)}{t}-\int \frac{\cos(t)}{t^2}dt
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
si(x) 
&= - \int_x^{\infty} \frac{\sin(t)}{t} dt \\
&=-(-\frac{\cos(t)}{t}-\int \frac{\cos(t)}{t^2}dt)|_x^{\infty}\\
&=\frac{\cos(t)}{t}|_x^{\infty}-\int_x^{\infty} \frac{\cos(t)}{t^2}dt\\
&=-\frac{\cos(x)}{x}-\int_x^{\infty} \frac{\cos(t)}{t^2}dt\\
\end{array}
$

so

$\begin{array}\\
\big|si(x)+\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\big| 
&\le |\int_x^{\infty} \frac{\cos(t)}{t^2}dt|\\
&\le |\int_x^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^2}dt|\\
&= |\dfrac{1}{t}\big|_x^{\infty}|\\
&= \dfrac{1}{x}\\
\end{array}
$